# Issue with Single Sign On With Jboss 7

Tags: java, single-sign-on, jboss7.x

I am following the [tutorial](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/jboss-security/configuring-single-signon-on-jboss-as-7) for single sign on.

My web.xml is like below.

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>secret</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.tomcat.demo.SalaryServer</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>secret</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/test</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>SecretProtection</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/servlet/SalaryServer</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/servlet/secret</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/test</url-pattern>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
        <http-method>POST</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
<auth-constraint>
<role-name>admin</role-name>
</auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<login-config>
<auth-method>
FORM
<!-- BASIC, DIGEST, FORM, CLIENT-CERT  -->
</auth-method>
<form-login-config>
<!--  only useful for FORM  -->
<form-login-page>/loginpage.html</form-login-page>
<form-error-page>/errorpage.html</form-error-page>
</form-login-config>
</login-config>
<security-role>
<role-name>admin</role-name>
</security-role>
</web-app>
```

Even if I use the correct login its going to the error page. Please let me know what is the issue ?

Comment: Have you specified a security domain in your jboss-web.xml file?

Comment: Yes, also its added in the standalone.xml

Comment: How are you testing it? Are you aware that you should not access the login page directly? It will be presented automatically as soon as you attempt to access a protected resource, such as `/servlet/SalaryServer`.

Comment: After delploying it in jboss
I am hitting the url http://localhost:8080/tomcatDemo/test and its showing the login page. But always throwing the error saying wrong user name or password

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is resolved by making the security domain as other in the jboss-web.xml